# vlookup to find match and return another element in row

Tags: vlookup

i have two sheets. first column of both sheets has userids, but there is only some overlap of ids between the two sheets. i want to keep the userids in the first sheet, but in the second sheet, the second column has a point of data that i want. for those userids in the first sheet that are also in the second sheet, i want to get this data.

so, for say the first row's userid in the first sheet, how could i use vlookup to find that same userid in the second sheet (if it exists), get the value of the second column of that match, and bring it back to the second column of the first sheet?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify and put this formula into the first cell of the second column on the first worksheet. Then copy and paste it down the column:

=VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet2!A$1:B$100, 2, FALSE)

Let's look at the parameters for this function:

1. A1: This value, on this worksheet, is what we're searching for in the range given in the next parameter. When you copy and paste the entire formula down the column, it increments the row # with each row. In row 2, it will be modified to A2, and so on.
2. Sheet2!A$1:B$100 : This is the range that we are interested in, on the second worksheet. It is the top left to bottom right cell. The $ symbol tells Excel not to change the row #'s when you copy and paste the formula down the column. Modify B$100 to fit the range of data you are interested in... something like B$30 if you only have 30 rows of id's on the 2nd sheet.
3. 2: This is the column you are interested in retrieving the value, relative to the above parameter. In this case, the 2 corresponds with column B.
4. False: This instructs Excel to find the exact match.